# Regarding HTTPs bandwidth control on server side

Tags: c++, c, apache, http, https

Requirement:

- Client supports 2MBPS bitrate and it will be sending HTTPS CURL request to server
- Server supports 1000kbps bitrate.So it has to send the data at the speed of 1000kbps to the client..
- But In my case,Server doesn't validating the bitrate which i've set.Instead its sending the data at rapid speed to the client.Now my requirement is to control the bandwidth on server side and send the data at the specified rate of 1000kbps.
- Be able to fetch the bitrate from code level: I need some clue about how we need to handle the bitrate at socket level for HTTPS.

Could someone please guide me on achieving this?

Note:
For HTTP, it works properly because bit-rate is handled at socket level whereas for HTTPS, they use `ssl_write` library call to transfer the data. In that call, they are not dealing with bitrate.

If someone guide me about how to deal with this, it will be more helpful for me.

Comment: Applications wont need to bother about bit rates, they are taken care by lower layers of TCPIP stack, if you mean client sends requests faster than your server can process, i believe you need to optimize server procesing and make it reply faster.

Comment: If 'they' really are 'handlling [HTTP] at socket level' there is no reason why 'they' can't use the same techniques via `ssl_write()`. But if the server only supports 1000Kbps, and that is also the desired bitrate, there doesn't seem to be any actual work to be done here. In any case I agree with @Pras: you don't want to waste any time whatsoever in your server: you want to get the request out as fast as possible and turn to the next one. Let TCP/IP and the network manage the bandwidth. They're good at that.

Comment: @pras::If we are dealing with one or two https requests,then it won't cause any issues.Incase if you are sending "n" nr of https requests,it causes some issues .   1)for first few requests,it allocates the complete bandwidth.But for the remaining requests,it doesn't have bandwidth to transfer data so it is getting hanged...

Comment: @EJP:ssl_write is a library call used to transfer the https data in a secured manner.we can't fill the bitrate into that and can't force it to manage bandwidth.if we forced to do that,it fails

Comment: You can choose how often you call it, but I don't see why any of this should be considered necessary. Your diagnosis of your problem seems flawed. If your server is hanging you should investigate the hanging, not try to throttle it.

Comment: https is quite slower than http due to ssl handshake,one of the (possiblly many)reasons your server hangs could be cpu being driven so busy it cant process new request